# How to refresh my HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating a Windows Phone 7 app which allow to listen a web radio. But I also want to get the cover of the song and I want it to be refreshed every 3 minutes for example.

When I start debugging my app, I've no problem but I've no idea how to call back my code to refresh the cover.

Thanks a lot.
Aymeric.

Comment: Are you using an <Image> in XAML and pointing it to some URI that contains the cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution not really the one I looked for but my mates used a timer to refresh the same application for Android and iOS since there is no push notification from the server.

So I used this code

```
DispatcherTimer refreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
refreshTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshTimer_Tick);
refreshTimer.Start();
```

Thank you all for the time you spent on this question.

Aymeric.